# Using sequence matcher in Python to find the longest common string

Tags: python, sequence

I was trying to use `difflib.SequenceMatcher` in Python to return the largest common string

```
string1="""ERROR agave_util.py:64 Timed out waiting for HA alert generated CRITICAL ha_test_util.py:44 HA alert generated, Stack:File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 909, in <module>    main(FLAGS, sync_state)  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 878, in main    worker.run(sync_state)  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 326, in run    if not self.__test_phase_wrapper(test_method):  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 502, in __test_phase_wrapper    func()  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 87, in test_stargate_master_power_off    self._host_power_off_test_cycle(host_of_stargate_master)  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 27, in _host_power_off_test_cycle    self.ha_util.power_off_and_check_ha(host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 469, in power_off_and_check_ha    self.wait_for_ha_alert(cutoff_usecs=latest_alert_start, **kwargs)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 418, in wait_for_ha_alert    interval=interval,  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 44, in wait_for_true    CHECK(result, message) ERROR nutanix_test_runner_worker.py:595 Test failed: 1exc_type: <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>exc_value: 1stack:   File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 502, in __test_phase_wrapper    func()  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 87, in test_stargate_master_power_off    self._host_power_off_test_cycle(host_of_stargate_master)  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 27, in _host_power_off_test_cycle    self.ha_util.power_off_and_check_ha(host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 469, in power_off_and_check_ha    self.wait_for_ha_alert(cutoff_usecs=latest_alert_start, **kwargs)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 418, in wait_for_ha_alert    interval=interval,  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 44, in wait_for_true    CHECK(result, message)  File "/main/.python/util/base/log.py", line 204, in CHECK    FATAL(log_msg, **kwargs)  File "/main/.python/util/base/log.py", line 185, in FATAL    sys.exit(1) ERROR nutanix_test.py:696 Failed to get gflags from 10.5.132.157. ERROR nutanix_test.py:696 Failed to get gflags from 10.5.132.157. ERROR nutanix_test.py:1699 Failed to save cluster configuration"""

string2="""ERROR agave_util.py:64 Timed out waiting for VMs [u'vm_353ca5', u'vm_e02d7f'] power on CRITICAL ha_test_util.py:44 VMs [u'vm_353ca5', u'vm_e02d7f'] power on, Stack:File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 909, in <module>    main(FLAGS, sync_state)  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 878, in main    worker.run(sync_state)  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 326, in run    if not self.__test_phase_wrapper(test_method):  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 502, in __test_phase_wrapper    func()  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 67, in test_zoo_keeper_leader_power_off    self._host_power_off_test_cycle(leader_host)  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 27, in _host_power_off_test_cycle    self.ha_util.power_off_and_check_ha(host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 468, in power_off_and_check_ha    self.verify_vms_not_on_host(host_vms, host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 617, in verify_vms_not_on_host    self.wait_for_vms_power_on(vm_names, per_vm_timeout)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 599, in wait_for_vms_power_on    interval=15)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 44, in wait_for_true    CHECK(result, message) ERROR nutanix_test_runner_worker.py:595 Test failed: 1exc_type: <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>exc_value: 1stack:   File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 502, in __test_phase_wrapper    func()  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 67, in test_zoo_keeper_leader_power_off    self._host_power_off_test_cycle(leader_host)  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 27, in _host_power_off_test_cycle    self.ha_util.power_off_and_check_ha(host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 468, in power_off_and_check_ha    self.verify_vms_not_on_host(host_vms, host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 617, in verify_vms_not_on_host    self.wait_for_vms_power_on(vm_names, per_vm_timeout)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 599, in wait_for_vms_power_on    interval=15)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 44, in wait_for_true    CHECK(result, message)  File "/main/.python/util/base/log.py", line 204, in CHECK    FATAL(log_msg, **kwargs)  File "/main/.python/util/base/log.py", line 185, in FATAL    sys.exit(1) ERROR nutanix_test.py:696 Failed to get gflags from 10.5.132.156. ERROR nutanix_test.py:696 Failed to get gflags from 10.5.132.156. ERROR nutanix_test.py:1699 Failed to save cluster configuration"""

match = SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2).find_longest_match(0, len(string1), 0, len(string2))
print match
print(string1[match.a: match.a + match.size])

string1="""ERROR agave_util.py:64 Timed out waiting for HA alert generated CRITICAL ha_test_util.py:44,"""
string2="""ERROR agave_util.py:64 Timed out waiting for VMs [u'vm_353ca5', u'vm_e02d7f'] power on CRITICAL ha_test_util.py:44"""
match = SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2).find_longest_match(0,    len(string1), 0, len(string2))
print(string1[match.a: match.a + match.size])
```

So basically during comparison of `string1` and `string2`  [first two lines] returns `CRITICAL ha_test_util.py:44`,
while when I cut some lines from `string1` and `string2` [lines 6 and 7], it returned  `ERROR agave_util.py:64 Timed out waiting for`

Basically my question is why sequence matcher didn't return the proper match  during my first case?

Comment: Where does `SequenceMatcher` come from?  I've never heard of it and am too lazy to search, risking that I find something else you are not using …

Comment: @Alfe - chances are that it comes from the built-in `difflib` module.

Comment: @zwer Right, already looking at that ;-)  My comment also tried raise awareness of the necessity of mentioning such things.  Others might have just skipped that Q just because of the hassle of finding that out.

Comment: @Alfe its from difflib module   
https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are experiencing (in your case negative) effects of `SequenceMatcher`'s *automatic junk heuristic*. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher):

> **Automatic junk heuristic**: `SequenceMatcher` supports a heuristic that automatically treats certain sequence items as junk. The heuristic counts how many times each individual item appears in the sequence. If an item’s duplicates (after the first one) account for more than 1% of the sequence and the sequence is at least 200 items long, this item is marked as “popular” and is treated as junk for the purpose of sequence matching. This heuristic can be turned off by setting the `autojunk` argument to `False` when creating the `SequenceMatcher`.

In `SequenceMatcher` constructor, `autojunk` defaults to `True`. If you try with `autojunk=False`, you'll get the expected longest match:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

string1 = """ERROR agave_util.py:64 Timed out waiting for HA alert generated CRITICAL ha_test_util.py:44 HA alert generated, Stack:File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 909, in <module>    main(FLAGS, sync_state)  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 878, in main    worker.run(sync_state)  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 326, in run    if not self.__test_phase_wrapper(test_method):  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 502, in __test_phase_wrapper    func()  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 87, in test_stargate_master_power_off    self._host_power_off_test_cycle(host_of_stargate_master)  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 27, in _host_power_off_test_cycle    self.ha_util.power_off_and_check_ha(host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 469, in power_off_and_check_ha    self.wait_for_ha_alert(cutoff_usecs=latest_alert_start, **kwargs)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 418, in wait_for_ha_alert    interval=interval,  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 44, in wait_for_true    CHECK(result, message) ERROR nutanix_test_runner_worker.py:595 Test failed: 1exc_type: <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>exc_value: 1stack:   File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 502, in __test_phase_wrapper    func()  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 87, in test_stargate_master_power_off    self._host_power_off_test_cycle(host_of_stargate_master)  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 27, in _host_power_off_test_cycle    self.ha_util.power_off_and_check_ha(host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 469, in power_off_and_check_ha    self.wait_for_ha_alert(cutoff_usecs=latest_alert_start, **kwargs)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 418, in wait_for_ha_alert    interval=interval,  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 44, in wait_for_true    CHECK(result, message)  File "/main/.python/util/base/log.py", line 204, in CHECK    FATAL(log_msg, **kwargs)  File "/main/.python/util/base/log.py", line 185, in FATAL    sys.exit(1) ERROR nutanix_test.py:696 Failed to get gflags from 10.5.132.157. ERROR nutanix_test.py:696 Failed to get gflags from 10.5.132.157. ERROR nutanix_test.py:1699 Failed to save cluster configuration"""
string2 = """ERROR agave_util.py:64 Timed out waiting for VMs [u'vm_353ca5', u'vm_e02d7f'] power on CRITICAL ha_test_util.py:44 VMs [u'vm_353ca5', u'vm_e02d7f'] power on, Stack:File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 909, in <module>    main(FLAGS, sync_state)  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 878, in main    worker.run(sync_state)  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 326, in run    if not self.__test_phase_wrapper(test_method):  File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 502, in __test_phase_wrapper    func()  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 67, in test_zoo_keeper_leader_power_off    self._host_power_off_test_cycle(leader_host)  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 27, in _host_power_off_test_cycle    self.ha_util.power_off_and_check_ha(host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 468, in power_off_and_check_ha    self.verify_vms_not_on_host(host_vms, host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 617, in verify_vms_not_on_host    self.wait_for_vms_power_on(vm_names, per_vm_timeout)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 599, in wait_for_vms_power_on    interval=15)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 44, in wait_for_true    CHECK(result, message) ERROR nutanix_test_runner_worker.py:595 Test failed: 1exc_type: <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>exc_value: 1stack:   File "/main/qa/py/qa/agave/nutanix_test_runner_worker.py", line 502, in __test_phase_wrapper    func()  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 67, in test_zoo_keeper_leader_power_off    self._host_power_off_test_cycle(leader_host)  File "/main/qa/test/agave/acropolis_tests/ha/best_effort_power_off_test.py", line 27, in _host_power_off_test_cycle    self.ha_util.power_off_and_check_ha(host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 468, in power_off_and_check_ha    self.verify_vms_not_on_host(host_vms, host)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 617, in verify_vms_not_on_host    self.wait_for_vms_power_on(vm_names, per_vm_timeout)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 599, in wait_for_vms_power_on    interval=15)  File "/main/.python/qa/util/agave_tools/ha_test_util.py", line 44, in wait_for_true    CHECK(result, message)  File "/main/.python/util/base/log.py", line 204, in CHECK    FATAL(log_msg, **kwargs)  File "/main/.python/util/base/log.py", line 185, in FATAL    sys.exit(1) ERROR nutanix_test.py:696 Failed to get gflags from 10.5.132.156. ERROR nutanix_test.py:696 Failed to get gflags from 10.5.132.156. ERROR nutanix_test.py:1699 Failed to save cluster configuration"""

match = SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2, autojunk=False).find_longest_match(0, len(string1), 0, len(string2))
print(match)
```

Output:

```
Match(a=110, b=156, size=534)
```

To be sure, we can check all matching blocks and find the longest:

```
>>> max(SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2, autojunk=False).get_matching_blocks(),
...     key=lambda m: m.size)
Match(a=110, b=156, size=534)
```

---

To illustrate the effects of `autojunk`ing on a simpler example, let's have a look what happens here:

```
>>> a = "aa:bb:cc" + ":"*200
>>> b = "aa:bb" + ":"*200
>>> SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).find_longest_match(0, len(a), 0, len(b))
Match(a=0, b=0, size=6)     # : is classified as junk
>>> SequenceMatcher(None, a, b, autojunk=False).find_longest_match(0, len(a), 0, len(b))
Match(a=8, b=5, size=200)   # : is NOT classified as junk
```

In the first case (with default `autojunk=True`) the `:` is considered a junk character (it represents more than 1% of the sequence that's at least 200 items long), and as the result, the longest match that ["looks right to people"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) is only 6 characters (the initial six).

In the second case (with explicit `autojunk=False`), the junk heuristics is off, and so the longest match is the last 200 characters.

If you repeat the same test for shorter sequences (shorter than 200 characters), you can see the `autojunk` makes no difference, since the junk heuristics is turned off (see in [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/difflib.py#L328)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I almost felt that I discovered a new bug of Python!

Comment: @PhilipTzou, you’re welcome! Python standard library sure has its tricky parts.